# Android SeekBar popups and LabelFor Property

Tags: android, widget, seekbar

I want display text popup above android SeekBar, like picture below (snapshot from Goole Play Books app).
[image: seekbar with popups]
I have a look in SeekBar properties in XML Layouts and found a LabelFor property. I'm wondering if it helps about my problem or not? 
Anyway my main concern is how to display such popups?